# I cannot get user details from Google Plus

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

The line Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) returns null even though I have already signed in and my app is already connected to the account.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mSignInClicked = false;
    Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);

    String personName = "No one!";
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
        String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + personName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Log cat also shows:
Error requesting visible circles: Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution = null}

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: thats probably due to the package name. What is your package name and what is the package name you put into developers console ?

Comment: My package name is okay and I am already signed in @MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: is "No one" is a valid user?

Comment: "No one!" is only assigned to personName to inform me if it really got the display name of the user.

The real problem is that it did not go in the if statement because Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) is null. @MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: Google+ API  is enabled in developer console ?

Comment: Google+API was not enabled in your console ?

Comment: If yes, I can post this as answer, so others gets benefit from it.

Comment: Yes @MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: Accept upvote for others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Enable Google+ API in Google Developer Console.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. It is giving me this error: Error requesting visible circles:Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}. Can anyone help me please.

Comment: giving single line of error doesn't help, if possible give stacktrace and explain your problem in detail

Comment: Sorry for giving only the error. I have already posted regarding the issue in some other thread but not getting much help. Can you please check the below thread which is having a more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960655/getting-exception-while-login-using-google-plus-in-android